# How to limit the project scan only to the com.home.controller package. Swagger

Tags: swagger-ui

Configuration is set to scan the entire project. How to change to scan only com.home.controller

```
@Bean
public Docket api(){
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Look at class `RequestHandlerSelectors`:

http://springfox.github.io/springfox/javadoc/2.6.0/springfox/documentation/builders/RequestHandlerSelectors.html

It has 4 methods and one of them is `basePackage()`.

Use it and put in " " address of your package like so:

```
@Bean
public Docket api(){
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.home.controller"))
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build();
}
```